# Which is faster, equalsIgnoreCase or compareToIgnoreCase

Tags: java, string

In a java app, assuming I have option of choosing the following comparison methods

**equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)**

**compareToIgnoreCase(String str)**

Which one is faster?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`equalsIgnoreCase` *can* be a lot faster. For example, consider two strings which start with the same 10,000 characters - but one of them has an extra character at the end. `equalsIgnoreCase` can return immediately; `compareToIgnoreCase` has to iterate to the end of the string to see the difference.

But generally I'd go with whichever expresses your intention better. This works well for performance too: assuming I'm right in saying that `equalsIgnoreCase` is at least as fast as `compareToIgnoreCase`, it means you should use that where you can - if you need an actual ordering, you've got to use `compareToIgnoreCase` anyway.

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase() has some crucial differences to compareToIgnoreCase(). For 1, it tests for == equality first before doing an actually seeing if all the characters are the same. CompareTo will always do a full comparison of the characters, but it will not take locale into consideration. So you really need to know which comparison to use and then benchmark it.

Answer (score 9):

if you worry about performances... **measure it**

Comment: Too easy! There has to be a way that wastes more people’s time!

Comment: indeed, very nice answer it isn't?

Comment: It's actually very easy to come to wrong conclusions using measuring in this case, since the outcome very much depends on exactly what you measure.  It's good to garner some insight first - see Jon Skeet's answer for a good example.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the source for java.lang.String

```
 public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) {
    return (this == anotherString) ? true :
           (anotherString != null) && (anotherString.count == count) &&
       regionMatches(true, 0, anotherString, 0, count);
 }
```

So, before it looks at the actual string character by character (which also happens in a similar fashion for `compareToIgnoreCase`), `equalsIgnoreCase` also checks for reference identity and character length, which could be very much faster.

Comment: Or it could be a waste of time when most strings are different :)

Comment: sure, it's a trade-off. But these two comparisons are very fast, so you lose not much. And the length comparison should be quite effective (detect a lot of different string very quickly).